# Apache Flink: Window is not triggered if the data stream "splitted"

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a Flink job processing the data stream with windowing as follows:

```
    StreamExecutionEnvironment env = ...;
    FlinkKafkaConsumer011<MyType1> consumer = ...;
    AssignerWithPunctuatedWatermarks<MyType1> myAssigner = ...;
    SingleOutputStreamOperator<MyType1> stream = env
        .addSource( consumer )
        .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks( myAssigner );

    ProcessFunction<MyType1, MyType2> preProcessor = ...;
    ProcessAllWindowFunction<MyType2, MyType3, TimeWindow> processor = ...;
    RichSinkFunction<MyType3> mySink = ...;
    stream
        .process( preProcessor )
        .windowAll( TumblingEventTimeWindows.of( Time.seconds( 60 ) ) )
        .process( processor )
        .addSink( mySink );
```

This code works as expected triggering the windows every corresponding 60 seconds. But if the code is modified/appended to produce an additional stream

```
    __HERE_THE_WHOLE_ABOVE_CODE__

    ProcessFunction<MyType1, MyType4> processor2 = ...;
    RichSinkFunction<MyType4> mySink2 = ...;
    stream
        .process( processor2 )
        .addSink( mySink2 );
```

then no one window on the first stream will be triggered at all. I don't want the additional stream be processed with windowing. How to make it - one stream windowed, another not?

Thank you.

Comment: This should work fine. When are you calling env.execute()? What does the job graph look like in the Flink dashboard?

Comment: Surely, I call env.execute() AFTER adding the second processing and sink.
But the graph looks very strage:
`Source: Kafka(tracking-events) -> (Timestamps/Watermarks -> Process, Filter -> Process -> Sink: Unnamed) /* <- it looks as the "secondary" stream! */
--- HASH ---> TriggerWindow(TumblingEventTimeWindows(6000), ListStateDescriptor{...}, EventTimeTrigger(), AllWindowedStream.main(MyClass.java:79)) 
--- HASH ---> KeyedProcess -> Map -> Process -> Sink: Unnamed /* <- but this is the "main" stream after the secondary! */`

Comment: That's hard to follow in a comment. Could you add a screenshot of the graph to your question?

Comment: Thank you, David, for the hint - I've analyzed the job graph on various combinations of operators and suppose, the problem is resolved. But anyway, in some combinations the graph looked incomprehensibly